# Firebase initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for the back-end of my app, my firebase configuration looks like :

```
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'xx',
        authDomain: "xx",
        databaseURL: "xx",
        projectId: "xx",
        storageBucket: "xx",
        messagingSenderId: "xx",
        appId: "xx"
    }
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

my question is what if i some configuration data is incorrect.
So how to check if my Firebase database is initialized correctly ? thanks

Comment: You should copy the configuration from the firebase console it's self. If the configuration is incorrect you wouldn't be able to connect to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a test case to check if your configuration is valid.

```
const getPost = async () => {
  const snapshot = await firestore.collection('Posts').get();
  const myPosts = snapshot.docs.map(collectIdsAndDocs);
  console.log(myPosts);
  setPosts({ myPosts });
};

const createPost = async (post) => {
  const docRef = await firestore.collection('Posts').add(post);
  const doc = await docRef.get();
  console.log(doc);
};

createPost({ Title: 'My First Post', Content: 'My content' });
getPost();
```

Comment: Good evening Dallas Baker, thanks for your answer.
In my case, I am working with Firebase Realtime database, the problem is that the configuration data is saved by the client in front-end (each client create their own firebase)  and when I try to save this configuration on the back end, I don't know how to check if this configuration is correct.

Comment: There isn't a way to verify until you initialize firebase with the config given by the user. You would need to implement error handling, so when `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` fails you can inform the user that their information was incorrect.

Comment: hi thanks again for your answer, that's exactly what i want, notify the user in case of  incorrect information.
i will try to use unhandled errors, thank's